# PostgreSQL stored procedure with RETURNS TABLE(id integer) returning all NULLs

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure in PostgreSQL 8.4 that calls another stored procedure depending on the integer value passed in as a parameter. Those stored procedures are called such that they should return a relation with one integer column. The problem I am having is that the outer stored procedure always returns a relation with the correct number of rows but with all of the id's NULL.

Here is the stored procedure reduced to its simplest form:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spa(count integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT generate_series(1, count);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spb(count integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT generate_series(1, count);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conditional_relation_return(objectType integer, count integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    IF objectType = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT id FROM spa(count);
    ELSIF objectType = 2 OR objectType = 3 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT id FROM spb(count);
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And if you call it:

```
# select * from conditional_relation_return(1, 2);
 id 
----


(2 rows)
```

Or more specifically:

```
# select count(*) from conditional_relation_return(1, 2) where id is null;
 count 
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

But if you call one of the referenced stored procedures, you get the correct results:

```
# select * from spa(2);
 id 
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)
```

So why does conditional_relation_return return all NULLs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `id` of spa conflicts with the out parameter id (`RETURNS TABLE (id integer)`).  Postgresql 8.4 doesn't complain, it chooses id from out parameter id instead of the saner one(id of spa).

Postgresql 9.1's complain on your original code:

```
ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM spa(count)
               ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT id FROM spa(count)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "conditional_relation_return" line 4 at RETURN QUERY
```

To fix it, fully qualify the id on your query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conditional_relation_return(
    objectType integer, count integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    IF objectType = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT x.id FROM spa(count) as x;
    ELSIF objectType = 2 OR objectType = 3 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT x.id FROM spb(count) as x;
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Output:

```
test=# select * from conditional_relation_return(1, 2);
 id 
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)
```

---

Postgresql honors the column(s) name you choose  from your `RETURNS TABLE`. It still slot `x.id` to the `id` of your `RETURNS TABLE`.  So, even you decided to rename your `RETURNS TABLE` return column's name, it will still slot `x.id` to that name, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conditional_relation_return(
    objectType integer, count integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (hahah integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    IF objectType = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT x.id FROM spa(count) as x;
    ELSIF objectType = 2 OR objectType = 3 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT x.id FROM spb(count) as x;
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Output:

```
test=# select * from conditional_relation_return(1, 2);
 hahah 
-------
     1
     2
(2 rows)
```

Notice the `hahah` column

Comment: How funny. You are right. 8.4 silently swallows the ambiguous id error. Thanks!